# Access ID of data saved to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pdf-generation, puppeteer

I have a POST request that saves data to the database and then runs puppeteer to create a pdf based on the data just saved. Puppeteer vists a URL (get request /:id) and generates a PDF of that page. This all happens on a single POST request.

I need to pass the ID of the data saved on the POST request to a variable that will allow me to dynamically add the ID to the url used in puppeteer. This means the right data from the database is accessed when puppeteer makes the GET request to http://localhost:3000/${id}. With the right ID, the correct data is dynamically passed to my view using EJS. This means puppeteer generates a PDF based on the data saved on the POST request.

On a conceptual level - theres no way for my app to automatically know which data id I'm looking for on just a POST request. So this is the only way I can think of doing it.

My code isn't working properly because the ID is not being passed to the URL `await page.goto(`http://localhost:3000/${id}``. Where am I going wrong? I've been stuck on this for 2 weeks now and can't find a solution.

Thanks for your help.

```js
/* routes */
app.get("/form", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = params.id;
  Blog.findById(id).then((result) => {
    res.render("pdf", { blog: result });
  });
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const blog = new Blog({
    name: "Smileh",
    surname: "Smith",
    boiler: "ideal",
    installprice: "fiver",
    pmhun: "forty",
    pmsixty: "thirty",
    pmtwenty: "twenty",
    fuel: "gas",
    location: "kitchen",
    orientation: "vertical",
    ladders: "no",
    scaffolding: "no"
  });
  blog.save().then((result) => {
    //I need the ID of the data just saved to the database
    let id = {result.id}(async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      // I need to pass the data ID here into the URL
      await page.goto(`http://localhost:3000/${id}`, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2"
      });
      await page.pdf({
        path: "quote8.pdf",
        format: "A2",
        printBackground: true
      });

      await browser.close();
    })();
  });
});
```

Comment: Before `let id = {result.id}`, add `console.log(result);` and add the logged information to the post.

Comment: Here's the console.log(result) - https://snipboard.io/LuRXv1.jpg

Comment: Change `let id = {result.id}` to `let id = result._id`.

Answer (score 0):

`let id = result._id` instead of `let id = {result.id}`